# How can I use Material UI in Scala JS?

Tags: material-ui, scala.js

My team works with `Scala.js` and I wanna use [`Material-UI`](https://material-ui.com/). But those two's code types look very different. Most of the examples in `Material-UI` seem to be based on regular Javascript.

I've tried to search about that, but the information is very limited, so I couldn't get any useful information. Is there anyone using `Material-UI` with `Scala.js`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using most JS libraries from Scala.js, you need what is called a "facade" -- a strongly-typed Scala wrapper that describes how to use the weakly-typed JavaScript library.

There appear to be several Material UI facades, but most of them look a bit half-baked. I'd guess that the most mature is the one in Chandu's [scalajs-react-components project](https://github.com/chandu0101/scalajs-react-components) -- in general, Chandu has done more with React in Scala.js than most folks. The general top-level page for the project can be found [here](http://chandu0101.github.io/sjrc/).